# Converting cell data in Excel

Tags: excel

I don't do much with Excel and have this problem:

Suppose I have the following values in separate cells representing capacity:

```
500.00GB
6.00TB
5.00GB
```

and wanted to convert the values to represent capacity in `TB`.  The current data values are text.  How do I logically convert each cell to a value expressed in `TB`.  For example,

```
.5
6
.005
```

Thanks!

Comment: `=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)/INDEX({1,1000,1000000},MATCH(RIGHT(A1,2),{"TB","GB","MB"},0))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only have `TB` and `GB` as per your example. You you can use the following  where your string is in cell `A1`. Drag down as necessary

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)/IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="GB",1000,1)
```

As @tigeravatar commented, you can use something like this if you have `TB`, `GB` and `MB`:

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)/INDEX({1;1000;1000000},MATCH(RIGHT(A1,2),{"TB";"GB";"MB"},0),)
```

These formulas return number like this (general format):

```
0.5
6
0.005
```

---

If you prefer, you can also display similarly to your original data by wrapping a `TEXT` function around the previous suggestions:

```
=TEXT(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)/IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="GB",1000,1),"0.0##""TB""")
```

Which returns strings like this:

```
0.5TB
6.0TB
0.005TB
```

Comment: Thank a ton @tigeravatar and everyone else as well.  These options did exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: No problem. If this did the trick mark it as the accepted answer with the tick mark to the left of this answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have the values on the A column then on the B column type the following `=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)="GB",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)/1000,LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2))`
This looks up at the value and if the last part is GB then it divides it, otherwise it leaves it. If you want to further divide to lower scales, then you can use nested ifs `if(if(,,),)`
Let me know if this helps.